# Reference variable from object in another class

Tags: java

I've got two classes, one called "Territory" which constructs an object with the following variables: "posX" and "posY", like this:

```
public Territory(int column, int row)
{
    posX = column;
    posY = row;
}
```

Then in another class, "World" I do the following:

```
Territory territory1 = new Territory(0, 0);
```

But then when I try to reference some of the variables from that object, i.e. like this:

```
System.out.println("Coordinates: " + territory1.posX);
```

I get the error:

```
cannot find symbol - variable territory1
```

Any help?

EDIT:

Here are the full classes:

Territory:

```
public class Territory
{
    public int posX;
    public int posY;
    public int armies;
    public String owner;

    public Territory(int column, int row)
    {
        posX = column;
        posY = row;
        armies = 0;
        owner = null;
    }
}
```

World:

```
public class World
{
    public World()
    {
       Player player1 = new Player();
       Player player2 = new Player();

       Territory territory1 = new Territory(0, 0);
       Territory territory2 = new Territory(1, 0);
       Territory territory3 = new Territory(0, 1);
       Territory territory4 = new Territory(1, 1);     
    }

    public java.lang.String toString()
    {
        System.out.println(territory1.getposX);
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue is probably with the scope of `territory1` though, based on the error, and not with the access modifiers of its fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `toString()` method doesn't recognize 'territory1' because it was declared in the other method

This should work

```
public class World
{
     Territory territory1, territory2, territory3, territory4;

    public World()
    {
       Player player1 = new Player();
       Player player2 = new Player();

       territory1 = new Territory(0, 0);
       territory2 = new Territory(1, 0);
       territory3 = new Territory(0, 1);
       territory4 = new Territory(1, 1);     
    }

    public toString()
    {
        if( territory1 != null)
            System.out.println(territory1.posX);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both of these and neither worked, still getting the same error. I updated the post to show full code.

Comment: @RyanEder nahh. of course that won't fix your problem. why don't you post your full code earlier. your `toString()` method doesn't recognize `territory1` because it was declared in the other method

Comment: @Voicu not aware of it. It seem that my answer is totally out! deleting

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to access the attribute of a class in another class then it means the attribute is not visible to that class. Check the access specifier for the attributes. You may have to use a getter(public method to get the value of a private variable) for the variable.